# How to better design a system where a document language can be changed?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, database-design

My Elasticsearch deployment has a language-specific index; for example, the English index stores all the English documents, the german index stores all the german documents.

Below are the functionalities of our system:

1. Search happens in all the language-based indices, as the search query is not language-specific in the search bar.
2. Documents can be moved across different language indices.

We wanted to re-design a system due to a lot of bugs and performance issues when changing language causes re-indexing.  and thought of getting rid of different indices on language basis and store the current language of the document, and update it to a new language if there is a change of language, **but not sure of relevance issue in general and what is industry recommendations around this.**

Comment: Can you add more details what you want to express when you say `relevance issue`? How would a search query look like, is it based on the documents name or does it also search the content of the documents (aka full text search)? The 2nd point seems not to be related to your question, as it mainly seems to be an incorrect usage (that you do not prevent from the system side).  Adding more details about how one of your indexes looks like might be helpfull as well.

Comment: relevance issue as mentioned in the official ES doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/language-pitfalls.html#_incorrect_inverse_document_frequencies, also my search query is of type full text search and it searches the various fields like title, description inside the documents .